# Android current gps location incorrect

Tags: android, gps

I'm testing current gps location application using samsung spica 1.5 but it doesn't display my current location it just shows me another location.

Here is my code:

```
public class MaptestActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
     private MapView mapView = null;
        private LocationManager lm = null;
        private double lat = 0;
        private double lng = 0;
        private MapController mc = null;
        private MyLocationOverlay myLocation = null;
        private String current;
        private PositionMarkersList positionMarkersList = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(15);





        myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(getApplicationContext(), mapView);
        myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {       
            public void run() {
            mc.animateTo(myLocation.getMyLocation());
            mc.setZoom(17);


            }

        }); 

        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
        GeoPoint pp=myLocation.getMyLocation();

        //addPosition(pp); 
        if (myLocation.isMyLocationEnabled()!=false)
        {
            GeoPoint p =myLocation.getMyLocation();
            lat= p.getLatitudeE6();
            lng= p.getLongitudeE6();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                     "geolocalisation activÈ lat: "+lat+ " long: " +lng,
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                     "geolocalisation desactivÈe" ,
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myLocation.enableMyLocation();
        myLocation.enableCompass();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
            mapView.setSatellite(!mapView.isSatellite());
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(
            getBaseContext(),
            "Location change to : Latitude = " + lat + " Longitude = "
                + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setCenter(p);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }


 //ajout d'une position

        private void addPosition(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, current, current);
            positionMarkersList.addMarker(overlayitem);
        }

}
```

Does anyone have any idea about this please?

When I click run to test the app, I have list of means to test (virtual devices ...) but there is a "!" near the name of the phone and I don't know why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a virtual device with Google API.

Also, where  your device location is displayed, may I know how far the displayed location on the map is from your current location?

Comment: i'm in tunisia and it show me a location in french!!! i'm testing with real device!!! sumsung galaxy spica why it doesn't work?

Comment: when i made the test the message that i have is "geolocalisation desactivated"!! can this be on relation with my location or somthing like this?? may in tunisia i'm not sûre that gps work here!!

Comment: your mobile is not getting current location therefor your device will return last known location. according to my knowledge.       you can run Google Map application on device , clear all cached data of application and after that reload that application for your current location by doing this your device will try to get current location.

Comment: "geolocalisation desactivated"

it sounds like you may need to turn on gps in the preferences.

Comment: make sure that your gps is activated

Comment: in "settings" -> "location & security" -> "use GPS satellites" please activate this

Comment: try this application on other mobile if application result is different than this mobile. have u get toast of " "geolocalisation activÈ lat:  long:" ?

Comment: no i didn't get i got just "geolocalisation desactée"!! i have just this mobile to test with :'(

Comment: it means your condition " if(myLocation.isMyLocationEnabled()!=false)" return false, read official document for fetching location http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: yess it return false!! can u explain to me why? i find it diffucult to understand the official document!!

Answer (score 1):

make sure to include, the right permissions for location services in your AndroidManifest.xml!!!

GPS:
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

WIFI:
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

All permissions: [can be found here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: yes i included all these permission

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />

Answer (score 1):

```
public Location getCurrentLocation() {
    try {

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)     getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // ---Get the status of GPS---
        boolean isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // If GPS is not enable then it will be on
        if (!isGPS) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    "android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
            intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

        Location location = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location == null) {
            location = lm
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        return location;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```